# Why does it write that `is not handled`, despite the fact that it's registered?

Tags: python, handler, aiogram

I am developing a bot on aiogram python.
But the command /sender does not work.

Console:

```
2023-09-19 19:42:22,749 - [INFO] -  aiogram.dispatcher - (dispatcher.py).start_polling(524) - Start polling
2023-09-19 19:42:22,796 - [INFO] -  aiogram.dispatcher - (dispatcher.py)._polling(340) - Run polling for bot @edu_light_u_bot id=1111111111 - 'edu_light_bot'
2023-09-19 19:42:25,729 - [INFO] -  aiogram.event - (dispatcher.py).feed_update(171) - Update id=511111722 is not handled. Duration 14 ms by bot id=1111111111
2023-09-19 19:45:28,590 - [INFO] -  aiogram.event - (dispatcher.py).feed_update(171) - Update id=511111723 is not handled. Duration 16 ms by bot id=1111111111
```

```
main.py
import asyncpg
import asyncio
import logging
import contextlib

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.fsm.storage.redis import RedisStorage

from core.middlewares.dbmiddleware import DbSession
from core.settings import settings
from core.utils.commands import set_commands
from core.handlers import sender
from core.utils.sender_list import SenderList
from core.utils.sender_state import Steps


async def start_bot(bot: Bot):
    await set_commands(bot)
    await bot.send_message(settings.bots.admin_id, text='Бот запущен!')


async def stop_bot(bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(settings.bots.admin_id, text='Бот остановлен!')


async def create_pool():
    return await asyncpg.create_pool(user=settings.db.db_user, password=settings.db.dp_password,
                                     database=settings.db.db_database, host=settings.db.db_host,
                                     port=5432, command_timeout=60)


async def start():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format="%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] -  %(name)s - "
                               "(%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"
                        )
    bot = Bot(token=settings.bots.bot_token, parse_mode='HTML')
    pool_connect = await create_pool()
    storage = RedisStorage.from_url('redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)

    dp.update.middleware.register(DbSession(pool_connect))
    dp.startup.register(start_bot)
    dp.shutdown.register(stop_bot)
    
    
   

    dp.message.register(sender.get_sender, Command(commands='sender', magic=F.args),
                        F.chat.id == settings.bots.admin_id)
    
    dp.message.register(sender.get_message, Steps.get_message, F.chat.id == settings.bots.admin_id)
    
    
    
    dp.callback_query.register(sender.sender_decide, F.data.in_(['confirm_sender', 'cancel_sender']))
    
    dp.callback_query.register(sender.q_button, Steps.q_button)
    dp.message.register(sender.get_text_button, Steps.get_text_button, F.chat.id == settings.bots.admin_id)
    dp.message.register(sender.get_url_button, Steps.get_url_button, F.chat.id == settings.bots.admin_id, F.text)

    sender_list = SenderList(bot, pool_connect)
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types(), senderlist=sender_list)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(f"[!!! Exception] - {ex}", exc_info=True)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()

if name == "main":
    with contextlib.suppress(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        asyncio.run(start())
```

Log is clear, But this should not be `is not handled`, this should to be `handled`.

Comment: Are you sure?  Is there an API you have to call to say "OK, I handle this"?

Comment: When the /sender command is called, nothing happens and the debug in its function does not work, and the only thing that gets stuck is this 'is not handled'

Answer (score 0):

You mast write
dp.message.register(handle_start_command, Command(commands='sender'))
in
async def start():

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to register it like this:

```py
dp.message.register(
     sender.get_sender,
     Command(
          commands=['sender'], 
          magic=F.args
), F.chat.id == settings.bots.admin_id)
```